# How to truncate only selected text of dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, dropdownbox

I have a dropdown

```
<div>
<select id="ddlTruncate">
    <option selected="selected">Select </option>       
    <option value="1">tetetetetetetet </option>
    <option value="2">tetetetetetetetetetete </option>
    <option value="3">tetetetetettetete </option>        
</select>
</div>
```

I want to truncate only the selected value and if the value gets change in previous value should show the original value

```
 $('#ddlTruncate').change(function () {
     var textval = $('#ddlTruncate :selected').text(); 
     var ddlval= $(this).val();   
        if(textval.length > 5) {    
            $('#ddlTruncate :selected').text(textval.substr(0,4)+'…');
        }
 });
```

Currently when I am selected any other option then previous value is show refracting to original value. Please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/hurera1111/6x039o7w/

Comment: You will need to store the values before and after the change.

Comment: Agree w/ @ShaunakD - use `data` to store actual values, then on submit, or whatever, grab the value from the `data` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x039o7w/2/) here for you.

Store the actual text in the `data-text` for the `option`, then on change, change the text of all the `options` but not the `:selected` one.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain that .. 1- Store the actual text in attribute called data-text before substr it ... 2- loop through all options text but not selected and not first-child  using `:not(":selected,:first-child")` selector... 3- if any text of another option text match the selected text change previous one to the stored data from data-text

```
$('#ddlTruncate').on('change',function () {
     var textval = $('#ddlTruncate :selected').text(); 
     var ddlval= $(this).val();
        if(textval.length > 5) {
            $('#ddlTruncate :selected').attr('data-text',textval);
            $('#ddlTruncate :selected').text(textval.substr(0,4)+'…');
            var newtext = $('#ddlTruncate :selected').text(); 
            $('#ddlTruncate option:not(":selected,:first-child")').each(function(){
                if($(this).text() == newtext){
                    $(this).text($(this).attr('data-text'));
                }
            });
        }
 });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xumbrpa4/5/)